# With family or with the family

Tags: articles

Should I use the article 'the' before 'family' in this sentence:

> Working from home results in more time to spend **with family**.
>   Working from home results in more time to spend **with the family**.

And please could you give me an explanation.

Answer (score 3):

Either could be correct depending on the context, but "with family" (with no article) is most generally correct. "Family" without an article can refer to any type of relative and to the relatives of any number of people. For example:

> Our employees like the new policy. Working from home results in more time to spend with family.

Here we are talking about many families of many employees. If we said "the family" in the above context, we would be implying that all the employees are related, which is possible but unlikely.

---

I would use "the family" only if you are referring to a specific family. For example:

> My dad likes his job. Working from home results in more time to spend with the family.

In this case we really do mean one specific family, that of the father and the child.

Note that in this context we can also drop the article without really changing the meaning:

> My dad likes his job. Working from home results in more time to spend with family.

Without the article, we are again referring to family in general. However, we still understand that we are talking about the specific family of the father and child. As such, dropping the article is a safe choice in both situations.